# attribute names with dashes don't work with get_attribute (perl Selenium)

Tags: html, selenium, perl, attributes

```
use feature 'say';
$selen = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
$selen->get("http://www.google.com");
$elem = $selen->find_element('(//div[@data-responsive-height-resize])[1]');
say $elem->get_attribute('data-responsive-height-resize'); # this doesn't work
say $selen->execute_script('return arguments[0].getAttribute("data-responsive-height-resize")', $elem);  # this works
```

Is there a problem with `Selenium::Remote::WebElement::get_attribute` in that it can't handle dashes in the attribute name?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try adding a `1` like it says in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::WebElement#get_attribute) for `get_attribute`?

Comment: Yes, it worked!

Comment: I suppose I should add that as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding comment as answer.

In the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::WebElement#get_attribute) for `get_attribute` it says that you can use a boolean as second argument

> If you want to get the initial condition (e.g. the values in the tag hardcoded in HTML), pass 1 as the second argument.

So if you try that, you might get what you want. (And it seems it did work)